# Where does $\frac{3}{2}$ in $1<s\cdot\zeta(s+1) < \frac{3}{2}$ come from?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, euler-product

In his short [note](http://pollack.uga.edu/eulerprime.pdf) on Euler and the prime harmonic series, Professor of Mathematics Paul Pollack, makes the following intermediate statement about the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ for $s>1$, without explanation:

$$
1<s\cdot\zeta(s+1) < \frac{3}{2}
$$

**Question: Where does that $\frac{3}{2}$ comes from?**

---

My thinking ...

He says it follows from a lemma which in his note is the well known inequality:

$$
\frac{1}{s-1} <\zeta(s)< \frac{s}{s-1}
$$

.. which he expresses as

$$1<(s-1)\cdot \zeta(s)<s$$

Substituting $(s+1)$ for $s$ would lead to the following inequality:

$$1 < s \cdot \zeta(s+1) < s+1$$

Comment: Are there any further conditions on $s$? This doesn't make sense. Set for example $s=3$, or even worse $s\to\infty$. @RhysHughes thank you for clarification.

Comment: Maybe you meant $s(\zeta(s+1)-1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the document linked, *Lemma 3* provides the general result that $$1<(s-1)\zeta(s)<s$$ for every $s$, *but*, the *Lemma 4* statement which contains the $\frac 32$ restricts $s$ to $(0,\frac12)$. Indeed, in this case, we have that for each $s\in(0,\frac12)$: $$1<s\zeta(s+1)<\frac12\zeta \left(\frac32\right)<\frac32$$